# Jslint unexpected backslash

Tags: javascript, jslint

My code is:

```
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
```

I get:

> Unexpected '\'.

why do I get that? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to escape the `[` character when it appears as the first character inside a character class `[...]`.

You don't seem to need the class anyway. Try this:

```
name = name.replace(/\[/, "\\\[").replace(/\]/, "\\\]");
```